# How to reset nvidia gpu after error in golang through golang-nvml

Tags: go, error-handling, gpu, nvidia, nvml

is there any command to reset nvidia gpu after error happened in golang through golang-nvml?
i only found how to get GPU infos API in golang-nvml like:

```
nvml.DeviceGetCount()
nvml.DeviceGetHandleByIndex(i)
nvml.DeviceGetCudaComputeCapability(device)
```